# Start video calls with Google hangouts on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to start a video call with a specific person with Google hangouts using an intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is currently no way to do this using an Intent.

> Currently, the Google+ Hangouts Button only works for web apps.

Feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=385